# Scrolling lagged after applying the typeface in the Recycler view items

Tags: java, android

I am new to Recycler view in android and I am working on styling the text so I have done like that below is my adapter class.

```
 public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
    private String[] mDataset;
    private ArrayList mContactData = new ArrayList();
    Context context;

    // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
    // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
    // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public TextView mPhoneNumber;
        public TextView mContactName;
        public TextView mCallDuration;
        public TextView mCallType;
        private TextView mCallTime;
        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            mPhoneNumber = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.phone_number);
            mContactName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name_text);
            mCallDuration = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.call_duration_text);
            mCallType = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.call_type);
            mCallTime = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.date_time_text);
        }
    }

    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public MyAdapter(ArrayList mContactData,Context context) {
        this.mContactData = mContactData;
        this.context = context;
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.new_layout, parent, false);
        // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters

        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // - get element from your dataset at this position
        // - replace the contents of the view with that element
        Typeface typeface_rMedium = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "Roboto-Medium.ttf");
        Typeface typeface_rLignt = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "Roboto-Light.ttf");
        holder.mContactName.setText(mContactData.get(position).getContactName());

        holder.mPhoneNumber.setText(mContactData.get(position).getContactNumber());
        holder.mPhoneNumber.setTypeface(typeface_rMedium);
        holder.mCallDuration.setText(mContactData.get(position).getCallDuration()+" sec");
        holder.mCallDuration.setTypeface(typeface_rLignt);
        holder.mCallTime.setText(Utility.getFromatedDateTime(Long.parseLong(mContactData.get(position).getCallTime())));
        holder.mCallTime.setTypeface(typeface_rLignt);
        if(mContactData.get(position).getContactType().equalsIgnoreCase("STD")){
            holder.mCallType.setText("S");
        }else{
            holder.mCallType.setText("L");
        }

    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mContactData.size();
    }
}
```

After that the scrolling got lagged, So anybody guess what went wrong.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Try creating typeface and setting typeface in ViewHolder Constructor like below :

```
public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        mPhoneNumber = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.phone_number);
        mContactName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name_text);
        mCallDuration = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.call_duration_text);
        mCallType = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.call_type);
        mCallTime = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.date_time_text);
        // Add typeface lines here and remove below lines from onBindViewHolder() Method
        Typeface typeface_rMedium = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "Roboto-Medium.ttf");
        Typeface typeface_rLignt = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "Roboto-Light.ttf");
        mPhoneNumber.setTypeface(typeface_rMedium);
        mCallDuration.setTypeface(typeface_rLignt);
        mCallTime.setTypeface(typeface_rLignt);
    }
```

Remove those lines you have added from `onBindViewHolder()` method. Since the item views are reused no need to set typeface again and again.

Problem here maybe for each item you are creating typeface and setting it.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are creating a new typeface instance every time the view is bound. What would be more efficient would be to create it once either as an Adapter level instance or setup a font caching and store/retrieve it there.